# Custom payment method not appearing in checkout (Magento 2.4)

Tags: magento2.4

I have been trying for a few days to create a custom payment method in checkout to implement a payment gateway from a new payment provider. So far I have seen many informations and tutorials but nothing ever show up in the frontend (I have the option in the admin panel). Here is what I have so far:

app/code/Xpertics/Satimpayment/etc/adminhtml/system.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="1000" translate="label">
            <group id="satimpayment" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Satim Payment</label>
                <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="order_status" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>New Order Status</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status\NewStatus</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="sort_order" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1">
                    <label>Sort Order</label>
                    <frontend_class>validate-number</frontend_class>
                </field>
                <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Title</label>
                </field>
                <field id="allowspecific" translate="label" type="allowspecific" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Payment from Applicable Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Payment\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="51" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1">
                    <label>Payment from Specific Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                </field>
                <field id="payable_to" translate="label" sortOrder="61" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Make Check Payable to</label>
                </field>
                <field id="mailing_address" translate="label" type="textarea" sortOrder="62" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Send Check to</label>
                </field>
                <field id="min_order_total" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="98" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1">
                    <label>Minimum Order Total</label>
                    <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="max_order_total" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="99" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1">
                    <label>Maximum Order Total</label>
                    <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="model"></field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

app/code/Xpertics/Satimpayment/etc/frontend/di.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="offline_payment_instructions_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\InstructionsConfigProvider</item>
                <!--<item name="offline_payment_satimpayment_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Xpertics\SatimPayment\Model\SatimPaymentConfigProvider.php</item>-->
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Xpertics/Satimpayment/etc/config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <satimpayment>
                <model>Xpertics\SatimPayment\Model\Satimpayment</model>
                <title>Satim Payment</title>
                <payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
                <active>1</active>
                <is_gateway>1</is_gateway>
                <can_use_checkout>1</can_use_checkout>
                <can_authorize>1</can_authorize>
                <can_capture>1</can_capture>
                <can_refund>1</can_refund>
                <can_void>1</can_void>
                <can_cancel>1</can_cancel>
                <cctypes>AE,VI,MC,DI,JCB,CUP,DN,MI</cctypes>
                <useccv>1</useccv>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
            </satimpayment>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

app/code/Xpertics/Satimpayment/etc/module.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Xpertics_SatimPayment" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Payment"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Magento_OfflinePayments"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/Xpertics/Satimpayment/etc/payment.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<payment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Payment:etc/payment.xsd">
    <methods>
        <method name="satimpayment">
            <allow_multiple_address>1</allow_multiple_address>
        </method>
    </methods>
</payment>
```

app/code/Xpertics/Satimpayment/Block/Form/SatimPayment.php :

```
<?php


namespace Xpertics\SatimPayment\Block\Form;

class SatimPayment extends \Magento\Payment\Block\Form
{
    protected $_template = 'Xpertics_SatimPayment::form/satimpayment.phtml';
    }

}
```

app/code/Xpertics/Satimpayment/Block/Info/SatimPayment.php :

```
<?php

namespace Xpertics\SatimPayment\Block\Info;

class SatimPayment extends \Magento\Payment\Block\Info{
    protected $_template = 'Xpertics_SatimPayment::info/satimpayment.phtml';
}
```

app/code/Xpertics/Satimpayment/Model/Satimpayment.php :

```
<?php


namespace Xpertics\SatimPayment\Model;

use Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod;

class Satimpayment extends AbstractMethod
{
    const PAYMENT_METHOD_SATIMPAYMENT_CODE = 'satimpayment';
    protected $_code = self::PAYMENT_METHOD_SATIMPAYMENT_CODE;
    protected $_isOffline = true;
    protected $_formBlockType = \Xpertics\SatimPayments\Block\Form\SatimPayment::class;
    protected $_infoBlockType = \Xpertics\SatimPayments\Block\Info\SatimPayment::class;

    public function getPayableTo(){
        return $this->getConfigData('payable_to');
    }

    public function getMailingAddress(){
        return $this->getConfigData('mailing_address');
    }

    public function isAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null)
    {
        return parent::isAvailable($quote);
    }

}
```

app/code/Xpertics/Satimpayment/Model/SatimPaymentConfigProvider.php :

```
<?php

namespace Xpertics\SatimPayment\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as PaymentHelper;

class SatimPaymentConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface{
    protected $methodCode = SatimPayment::PAYMENT_METHOD_SATIMPAYMENT_CODE;
    protected $method;
    protected $escaper;

    public function __construct(PaymentHelper $paymentHelper, Escaper $escaper){
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->method = $paymentHelper->getMethodInstance($this->methodCode);
    }

    public function getConfig(){
        return $this->method->isAvailble() ?[
            'payment' => [
                'satimpayment' => [
                    'mailingAddress' => $this->getMailingAddress(),
                    'payableTo' => $this->getPayableTo(),
                ],
            ],
        ] : [];
    }

    protected function getMailingAddress(){
        return nl2br($this->escaper->escapeHtml($this->method->getMailingAddress()));
    }

    protected function getPayableTo(){
        return $this->method->getPayableTo();
    }
}
```

app/code/Xpertics/Satimpayment/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="satimpayment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Xpertics_SatimPayment/js/view/payment/satimpayment</item>
                                                                    <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="xpertics_satimpayment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/Xpertics/Satimpayment/view/frontend/templates/form/satimpayment.phtml :

```
<?php if ($block->getMethod()->getMailingAddress() || $block->getMethod()->getPayableTo()):?>
<dl class="items check payable" id="payment_form_<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getMethodCode()) ?>" style="display:none;">
    <?php if ($block->getMethod()->getPayableTo()) : ?>
        <dt class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Make Check payable to:')) ?></dt>
        <dd class="content"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getMethod()->getPayableTo()) ?></dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getMethod()->getMailingAddress()) : ?>
        <dt class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Send Check to:')) ?></dt>
        <dd class="content">
            <address class="checkmo mailing address">
                <?= /* @noEscape */ nl2br($block->escapeHtml($block->getMethod()->getMailingAddress())) ?>
            </address>
        </dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
</dl>
<?php endif; ?>
```

app/code/Xpertics/Satimpayment/view/frontend/templates/info/satimpayment.phtml :

```
<dl class="payment-method checkmemo">
    <dt class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getMethod()->getTitle()) ?></dt>
    <?php if ($block->getInfo()->getAdditionalInformation()) : ?>
        <?php if ($block->getPayableTo()) : ?>
            <dd class="content">
                <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Make Check payable to')) ?></strong>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getPayableTo()) ?>
            </dd>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($block->getMailingAddress()) : ?>
            <dd class="content">
                <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Send Check to')) ?></strong>
                <address class="checkmo mailing address">
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ nl2br($block->escapeHtml($block->getMailingAddress())) ?>
                </address>
            </dd>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</dl>
```

app/code/Xpertics/Satimpayment/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/satimpayment-method.js :

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
        'Magento_Payment/js/model/credit-card-validation/validator'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults:{
                template: 'Xpertics_SatimPayment/payment/satimpayment'
            },
            getMailingAddress: function () {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.satimpayment.mailingAddress;
            },
            getInstructions: function () {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions(this.item.method);
            },
            getCode: function(){
                return 'xpertics_sapimpayment';
            },
            isActive: function () {
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
);
```

app/code/Xpertics/Satimpayment/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/satimpayment.js :

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'xpertics_satimpayment',
                compoonent: 'Xpertics_SatimPayment/js/view/payment/method-renderer/satimpayment-method'
            }
        );
        return Component.extend({});

    }
);
```

app/code/Xpertics/Satimpayment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/satimpayment.html :

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio" name="payment[method]" class="radio" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <p data-bind="html: getInstructions()"></p>
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-role="review-save"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: I solved my problem. There was a few typos. Thanks